# Sigstop when trying to run script?

Tags: ksh, signals

I am trying to list out all commands by users, unfortunately I hit a weird sigstop that I am not sure how to diagnose?

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo '['
for USER in `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd |sed '/^#/ d'`; do
    if ! su $USER 2>&1 |grep 'unknown login'; then 
        echo "  {"
        echo "    USER: '$USER',"
        echo "    CMDS: '$(su $USER -c 'sudo -l')'"
        echo "  },"
    fi
done
echo ']'
```

The error

```
# ./sudoers.ksh
[
  {
    USER: 'nobody',
    CMDS: ''
  },
./sudoers.ksh: line 8: 27013: Stopped (SIGSTOP)
```

Comment: You can probably solve a lot of issues by using `getent` instead of direct `/etc/passwd` management, and don't use `su`. For example: `getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | while read user; do echo "$user - $(sudo -U $user -l)"; done`. One of your `su`s is probably in the background and is trying to read from the TTY, which is not allowed.

Comment: Unfortunetly getent is not an available command on OSX =/ This would work though on my Solaris / AIX / HPUX / OEL boxes though I assume =)